# composer install jquery plugins as component using component-installer

Tags: php, components, composer-php, asset-management

I am trying to install a jquery plugin using [component-installer](https://github.com/RobLoach/component-installer) , for which I have following composer.json file

```
{
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir": "assets/vendors",
    "component-dir": "assets/components"
  },
  "require" : {
    "robloach/component-installer": "*",
    "components/jquery": "2.*",
    "components/jqueryui": "1.11.*",
    "Krinkle/jquery-json": "dev-master"
  },
  "repositories": {
    "jquery-json" : {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "require": {
          "robloach/component-installer": "*"
        },
        "name": "Krinkle/jquery-json",
        "type": "component",
        "version": "master",
        "source": {
          "url": "git://github.com/Krinkle/jquery-json.git",
          "type": "git",
          "reference": "master"
        },
        "extra": {
          "component": {
            "scripts": [
              "dist/jquery-json.min.js"
            ]

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine but `Krinkle/jquery-json` is downloaded to `assets/vendors` directory instead of `asserts/components`. I have lots of plugins to setup this way if this experiment works, and defining all the plugins will increase the size of composer.json files . Is there a way to keep keep package files on external json file e.g `jquery-json.json` and include it in main composer.json file ?

Any other suggestion to manage assets/js components using composer will be much appropriated.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup looks quite complicated. I'd recommend you checking [composer-asset-plugin](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin) package, that allows pretty much the same. Just in more simple and fancy way.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please mark answer as correct solution, so other can see it's been resolved.

Comment: please add complete solution to problem , to be mark this as accepted , otherwise its still a suggestion which I appreciate thanks.

Comment: What do you require in solution to be complete?